# .net default event handler

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

In my product I need process wide events. For that I used code like this:

```
public class Global
{
    public static event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Message;
    public static void ShowMessage();
}
```

Now let's say I have a WinForms user interface. In form's code I will subscribe to this event and handle it in some default way (eg. by using System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show() method). Now the question is how do I allow user to create derived form and override my default Message event handler implementation?

Just subscribing to the event for the second time with custom implementation doesn't solve the problem (both event handlers would be executed and potentially two message boxes shown). The options I see are either:

```
//call OnSubscribeToMessageEvent() from either form's constructor or OnLoad event handler
protected virtual void OnSubscribeToMessageEvent()
{
    Global.Message += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(Global_Message);
}
private void Global_Message(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    //my default implementation
}
```

or

```
//subscribe in either form's constructor or OnLoad event handler
protected virtual void Global_Message(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    //my default implementation
}
```

Which version is better and why? Or maybe there are any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I still have some doubts as I have never seen such a design pattern in any .NET library

Yes, you're right to worry about this.  These kind of event subscriptions are very fickle, the event source always outlives the subscriber.  There's only one class in the framework I know that does this, SystemEvents.  The problem is that every subscriber has to *very carefully* unsubscribe itself when its lifetime ends or the object will stay referenced forever.  A memory leak that's very hard to diagnose.

A better pattern here is to use an interface.  Let's declare one:

```
public class MyEventArgs { /* etc.. */ }

public interface IGlobalNotification {
    event EventHandler Disposed;
    void OnMessage(MyEventArgs arg);
}
```

Now you can have a form implement the interface:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IGlobalNotification {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        GlobalMessages.Register(this);
    }

    void IGlobalNotification.OnMessage(MyEventArgs arg) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The Register method registers the form with the GlobalMessages class, the Dispose event ensures that the class can detect that the form is dying:

```
public static class GlobalMessages {
    public static void Register(IGlobalNotification listener) {
        listener.Disposed += delegate { listeners.Remove(listener); };
        listeners.Add(listener);
    }
    public static void Notify(MyEventArgs arg) {
        foreach (var listener in listeners) listener.OnMessage(arg);
    }

    private static List<IGlobalNotification> listeners = new List<IGlobalNotification>();
}
```

Call GlobalMessages.Notify() to get the OnMessage() method to run in all live form instances.  The major advantage of this approach is that a client programmer can never screw up.

Comment: Seems quite elegant. But this effectively means that .NET event mechanism cannot be used for something that essentially is an event. Suspicious. A somewhat similar pattern is used in COM (Advise/Unadvise methods + ISomethingEvents interface) but are you aware of any examples of such use in BCL?

Comment: And one more question: would you think that the `Disposed` event will ever be called? Note that we are still holding reference to our Form in `listeners` collection. So in my opinion we have a chicken and egg problem here.

Comment: Dispose() has nothing to do with references.  Winforms automatically calls it when you or the user closes the window.

Answer (score 2):

I would let the derived class override the `Global_Message`. The subscription to the event is generic and why would you want to implement it in every child again? It also gives you the option to call `base.Global_Message(sender, e)` in case your child class just wants to add some decoration to it and use the default behaviour otherwise.

Comment: I still have some doubts as I have never seen such a design pattern in any .NET library I have used (BCL in particular). Are you aware of any such examples?

Comment: Well, I can't point you to any specific. The only remark I can add is that I would not do the subscription inside the form. If you follow the MVP pattern then the event handling belongs into the presenter which then can do some business logic and call the appropriate action on the view.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer your second example, as that way, classes that extend your base class only have to override one method and do not have to remove the handler added by the base class from the event.

Comment: In both cases there is only one method to override. But in the first case the event handler is private and in the second one it is protected (and thus part of the interface).

Answer (score 0):

The key is adding the **virtual** keyword, so that a derived type can overide the method and the method they created will be called instead.

```
//subscribe in either form's constructor or OnLoad event handler
protected virtual void Global_Message(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
{
    //my default implementation
}
```

Comment: You are right, I just forgot about it (I corrected the question).

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've added virtual to both, I'd go with the first and override the one that subscribes to the event, if they didn't want the event subscribed to.

Though there is another option, call it #3.

```
protected EventHandler GlobalMessageEvent = new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(Global_Message);
protected virtual void OnSubscribeToMessageEvent() 
{
    // this could be done in the Form_Load() or constructor instead.
    Global.Message += GlobalMessageEvent;
}
```

Then potentially an inherited class could do somewhere: (note the **-=**)

```
{
    Global.Message -= GlobalMessageEvent;
}
```